# Sorting json array based on alphabets section in angularjs 2

Tags: javascript, html, json, css, angular2-routing

Below is an example . I have a json data , that data should be formatted and placed in the box accordingly to . data sorted in A-B should go to particular section . And it should be dynamic . I have tried a lot but not able to acheive
[image: sorted alphabetical elements]

The question doesn't contain any information about the code . Please apologize if the question is not in appropriate order . This is the logic I will have to perform based on the visual.

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you for the documentation . my question how to sort the elements accordingly into the particular box . New to typescript and javascript .mean while i will try to read the documentation thank you

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have specific JSON for it

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't have specific JSON for it . I seriously have no clue how to structure the json for the above example . I have made the same ui usng bootstrap 
`<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2" *ngFor="let item of items">
         <div class="row">{{item.country}}</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142234/discussion-between-naveenkg-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: I need an idea on how to do it or reference .This really looks new to me .I have posted an example to get clue on how to do it . Thank you very much

Comment: @JaromandaX I asked for a reference . I never meant in my question that plz outsource for me . Below is the solution for the question what I had posted earlier . Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the div that loops each div . used simple divs to make seven columns in a single row. Below is app.component.html

```
<div class="alphacolumn" *ngFor="let alpha of alphacustomer">
                <p class="sort">{{alpha.order}}</p>
                <div class="cus-box" *ngFor="let custo of alpha.data">
    {{custo.customer}}</div>
            </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-search',
    templateUrl: './search.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
    })
   export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  alphacustomer:any[];
  slectedCustomer:any;
  constructor() { 
  this.alphacustomer=[
    {
      order:"A-B",
      data:[
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
         {customer:"CountryNames"},
      ]
    },
    {
      order:"C-E",
      data:[
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
      ]
    },
    {
      order:"F-L",
      data:[
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
      ]
    },
    {
      order:"M-P",
      data:[
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
      ]
    },
    {
      order:"Q-S",
      data:[
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
      ]
    },
    {
      order:"T-Z",
      data:[
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNames"},
        {customer:"CountryNamess"},
      ]
    }
];

  }
```